# Same 2.4 gHz SSID on new router shows up as a different network

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

I bought a new TP-Link AX1800 Router to replace my old AC3150 router. I set the same SSIDs for the 2.4 and 5gHz networks, and set the same passwords and security settings.

All my 5gHz devices connected to the new router no problem. And some 2.4gHz devices connected to the new router.

But some 2.4 gHz devices would not connect. They see the new network as being a different network when I plug in the old router. For example on my laptop there are two 2.4gHz networks with the same SSID, but they are listed separately. The 5gHz networks are recognized as being the same, so only one 5G network is listed.

Any thoughts on what is causing some devices (Google Nest Hub, Rachio smart sprinkler, Kasa wifi light switch) to not recognize the new network as the same as the old one? If it matters the SSID has capitol letters and a space in it.

Comment: This is only a guess but I would bet that those devices use the router's BSSID (Basic Service Set Identifier, the access point's MAC address) in addition to the SSID for added security.  Your new router has the same name be certainly has a different mac address.

Comment: What channel is it using? There are some channels (12-14) which are region specific and not supported in all devices.

Comment: Also, what bandwidth size. Anything above 20MHz may cause issues with some devices.

Comment: @davidgo the channels and bandwidth were set to auto on the old and and new router. The devices can see the new 2.4gHz network, but for some reason they don't recognize it as the same network as before.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That was a good idea, but it doesn't seem to have worked, or I was changing the wrong MAC address. should I match the new router LAN  MAC to the old router LAN MAC? or something else?

Comment: I don't understand changing the mac address.  How on earth can you change the router's mac address to match the old one?  That defeats to purpose of a mac address.